# How do I close a card when onclick on a button in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-ui card in which it contains image, input field, check-box and a submit button. In which card is displaying onclick on some other option which is not mentioned in the below code. I want to close a card when I click on submit. How can I achieve this?

```
     <Card
          className="details-card"
          style={{ paddingTop: "0px" }}
          color="primary"
        >
          <CardHeader
            style={{
              paddingBottom: 0,
              paddingTop: 0
            }}
            title="Image"
          />
          <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/?random" />
          <CardContent className="details-card-body">
            <TextField label="Name" fullWidth />
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <Typography>
                  New User
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={this.state.addNew}
                    name="addNew"
                    onChange={this.handleCheckBox("addNew")}
                    value="new user"
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Checkbox B" }}
                  />
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
              Click to Tag
            </Button>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
```

Here below is my code on CodeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/embed/lppzx48r0m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want to do
you'll need a flag to conditionally hide or show the card.
For example lets take `flag` variable in state, and change state variable `flag` based on submit button and on the basis of `this.state.flag` you can do

```
{this.state.flag ?
    (<Card
        className="details-card"
        style={{ paddingTop: "0px" }}
        color="primary"
    >
        //Card content
    </Card>)
    :
    null
}
```

You can also provide conditional css based on `this.state.flag`

```
<Card
    className="details-card"
    style={{ paddingTop: "0px", display: this.state.flag ? block : 'none'}}
    color="primary"
>
    //Card content
</Card>
```

P.S.: The second approach is not recommended because we are rendering element even if it is not needed.